# Unable to open routerLink when navigating backwards to last slide of IonSlides component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, routerlink, ionic-react

I have an infinitely looping IonSlides component with 5 slides. Each slide has a IonCard component which contains a routerLink to a different page in my app.

Scrolling through the slides forwards (eg/ thumb goes right to left), everything is fine - all the slides open up the correct link and the looping works correctly.

However, when you scroll backwards (thumb goes left to right) and land on the last card in the coded list (the 5th card - there is no 'last card' in an infinite loop) the link no longer opens it just redirects to the home page when it fails. Every other slide can be scrolled to backwards and the link will open correctly. It's just the last card in the IonSlides component which has this issue.

To verify this I've added a blank slide at a 6th slide to my list (so it will be in the last position). Now when scrolling back the 5th card will load the link correctly. Therefore I think there is an issue with the last card of a IonSlides carousel when scrolling backwards.

This issue has me pretty stumped, if anyone has any ideas/fixes I'd love to know, thanks.